# How to extract iteratively the compare_means value from a dataset

Tags: r, iteration, compare

I'm trying to apply the compare_means() function onto  this dataset

```
> dput(head(data_long, 300))
structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04"), GR = c("RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP"), SES = c("L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V"), COND = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC"), signals = c("P3(400-450).FCz", 
"P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz"), value = c(-13.733750856001, -9.75024624896264, 
2.65626156135631, -11.2145748677083, -8.14861856277773, 3.4315211013568, 
-7.774797181711, -5.0379636708446, 4.67200616533014, -0.397250087672501, 
2.91913936481813, 8.38141924882334, 9.61455213192824, -11.0706676917232, 
-8.42427447113084, 3.37360619561252, -13.9481657323772, -11.7645758007163, 
-1.55179922542943, -8.40872060176111, -6.36865552801825, 1.75888442936359, 
1.01519755373062, 1.85489998202138, 4.88842858528025, 7.21299011910717, 
-8.4719202003519, -5.61886494275071, 5.4043480635031, -12.0047623683783, 
-9.16726244915301, 1.13509020104859, -7.03235376576925, -4.54670193355435, 
2.49276476951357, -1.17300033366376, 0.694393606954545, 5.0594399581601, 
6.1861244061312, -5.04318152659785, 0.73152672768007, 19.5226358864568, 
-4.24372139176794, 0.918751423320568, 16.3120391015512, -0.65010821749741, 
4.05493850786385, 13.8997702651793, 0.663115370014327, 3.95694572160701, 
3.88831364571248, 6.46723813995257, -6.25375875400145, 1.11453058993788, 
18.5017390789352, -7.38414465678688, -0.674372568935879, 14.1694182774958, 
-3.24350263682843, 2.67516303169366, 13.2135623121441, -1.72160165493474, 
2.36649557381131, 5.83201076558185, 7.25962635499353, -7.0474968134059, 
-2.25104720773472, 11.7844254386573, -6.61221718491095, -2.47425935490564, 
9.04781409226351, -2.84832379590422, 1.02479302810681, 9.51479768101391, 
0.0540027107377267, 2.71292196345657, 3.65113189260335, 7.92952342178602, 
-11.6312151716924, -5.16524399006139, 11.8802266972569, -11.7785042972793, 
-5.96429031525769, 8.23981597718437, -5.67295796971287, -0.774461731301161, 
9.99385579756163, -0.198736254963744, 2.96437294922766, 6.28027312932027, 
7.91468942320841, -11.1438413285935, -5.53112490175437, 12.1053426662461, 
-9.14927207125904, -5.10918437158799, 9.51261484648731, -4.3918290080777, 
-0.650009462761383, 11.1212652173052, -3.16101041766438, -2.12913230708907, 
5.24535230966772, 9.94838815736199, -3.99591470944713, 0.621502123415388, 
12.955441582096, -7.58190508537766, -2.81732229625975, 9.42367409925817, 
-2.96652960658775, 1.14010250644923, 10.6989716871958, 0.895992279831378, 
2.94619035115619, 7.68162285335806, 10.2186482048953, 8.71618523084192, 
10.0972150696175, 13.9718285231429, 14.2438131545118, 18.1277616996079, 
20.6284861844249, 12.5228696634748, 15.0856583318757, 15.4011622649207, 
9.21248347391488, 10.0673617448764, 8.55827491190151, 5.76901446016799, 
3.1567164130045, 3.29671672118792, 6.37710361710325, 10.3728637305957, 
14.0324104861749, 17.1194345279475, 10.1688421767607, 12.7218688256241, 
13.5845965959489, 4.2029104966206, 5.28032844958354, 4.37390045274906, 
1.63411653734436, 0.11779005903818, 0.527314779744752, 3.52040283490143, 
4.71555467505934, 7.88901307601169, 9.74981375898379, 4.94891653050796, 
7.04929483656524, 7.62145250862908, 5.29260474692784, 5.76317883868431, 
4.27567967018154, 2.14044069620066, 6.2230923800622, 7.48013969467974, 
13.9681839573434, 8.16263381384371, 10.9263261999576, 15.5578942384162, 
8.29234474523583, 9.71944484568732, 12.4214977980377, 4.43538787409554, 
4.54790063971537, 6.04702803069286, 4.09091078261671, 0.545039723311392, 
2.24297008138028, 8.64955428897889, 2.54754270788021, 5.40070389371842, 
10.3425870381822, 2.89989209310052, 5.19815917760722, 8.94731174966949, 
1.28346027317076, 2.16569592764593, 5.29458007289059, 5.32593378182311, 
-0.383605036065646, -0.0523505792147314, 2.80847380898547, -1.01463338713448, 
0.139150314055044, 3.41932708826405, 1.69916872833203, 2.20513206952329, 
4.10953557761617, 1.17003451023205, 1.33824716938448, 1.21234812875355, 
-0.0587064331536407, -2.10936383457265, 0.0473343786951428, 10.1644392609445, 
-6.4216236476269, -4.61042211238648, 4.05274207265641, -1.13332962482291, 
-0.20305866581144, 5.80373742668179, 3.21881665778703, 2.58426832963409, 
6.30887598671621, 6.86490468078958, 1.81064934015995, 2.78240093455642, 
13.2788201390174, -4.08374576377548, -3.5562551128714, 3.767844291789, 
0.649857280429136, 1.01053594416015, 5.74639215930458, 5.92604591551597, 
5.077230852852, 5.9614279900414, 5.26280996552585, 0.754416368133019, 
2.60057993978525, 10.5077997492971, -8.46742290376216, -6.85651693740331, 
0.326110657534835, -4.43684347222634, -2.96241685765962, 1.48762660613099, 
-2.75555354427229, -1.59699177169018, -0.609381826740468, 0.981300734684586, 
-1.2371236814317, 1.4302038359579, 13.4030666728381, -6.30908300837476, 
-2.17237957159954, 6.65839865279684, -2.31574543509226, 1.26480036715092, 
6.04018553841336, 2.18006640865321, 6.61872855398538, 3.66646157996528, 
5.0384350436334, -2.76852389876276, -0.650797837853182, 4.74014346829081, 
-6.72661142802369, -6.18867237684241, 1.17003883692158, -2.73359549382074, 
-2.00512841997728, 1.9050381096835, -0.225533814334514, -1.21696526578647, 
0.240956222277802, 0.361670119961531, 5.54144355778122, 7.81248993867768, 
11.9003140352528, -3.32736490042247, -1.77938930999718, 5.40630013085777, 
-0.38736451456005, -0.423105565152366, 6.37211228749408, 0.986467266459687, 
-0.507207892673482, 1.15053325116554, 0.393791410918138, -0.314155675382471, 
2.23100741241039, 15.0981004360619, -4.01515836011381, -1.43557366487622, 
5.06332653216481, 0.159183652691071, 1.51403741206392, 3.7899021820967, 
3.11042068112836, 3.44844607014521, 1.08242973465635, 1.07455889922813, 
0.238885648959708, 3.96990710862955, 15.4046229884164, -6.60165385653499, 
-3.14872157912645, 5.02619159395405, -1.78361184935376, 0.25571835554024, 
4.59413830322224, 2.27800090558473, 3.02403433835637, 2.99896314000211, 
1.65917850515029, 5.03749946898385)), row.names = c(NA, -300L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

I would like to report the comparisons like this:

compare_means(value ~ COND, group.by = 'SES', data = data_long)

BUT IT SHOULD BE STRATIFIED FURTHERMORE FOR EACH OF THE 13 SIGNALS as well. Can anyone help? I've tried running this code, but the output is incorrect I am suppose to obtain 13 output for every signals

```
 > data_long %>% 
+   group_by(signals) %>% 
+ compare_means(value ~ COND, group.by = 'SES', data = .)
Adding missing grouping variables: `signals`
# A tibble: 9 x 9
  SES   .y.   group1  group2         p   p.adj p.format p.signif method  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 L     value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC 4.42e- 1 4.8e- 1 0.44185  ns       Wilcoxon
2 L     value NEG-CTR NEU-NOC 5.76e-13 5.2e-12 5.8e-13  ****     Wilcoxon
3 L     value NEG-NOC NEU-NOC 1.24e-10 8.7e-10 1.2e-10  ****     Wilcoxon
4 R     value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC 5.90e- 4 3  e- 3 0.00059  ***      Wilcoxon
5 R     value NEG-CTR NEU-NOC 8.99e-11 7.2e-10 9.0e-11  ****     Wilcoxon
6 R     value NEG-NOC NEU-NOC 7.52e- 4 3  e- 3 0.00075  ***      Wilcoxon
7 V     value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC 2.41e- 1 4.8e- 1 0.24145  ns       Wilcoxon
8 V     value NEG-CTR NEU-NOC 2.57e- 3 7.7e- 3 0.00257  **       Wilcoxon
9 V     value NEG-NOC NEU-NOC 2.65e- 5 1.6e- 4 2.7e-05  ****     Wilcoxon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to pass both grouping variables in a vector to the `group.by` parameter:

```r
ggpubr::compare_means(value ~ COND, data_long, group.by = c('SES', 'signals'))

#> # A tibble: 117 x 10
#>    SES   signals       .y.   group1  group2     p p.adj p.format p.signif method
#>    <chr> <chr>         <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr> 
#>  1 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-CTR NEG-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#>  2 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-CTR NEU-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#>  3 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-NOC NEU-N~   0.7     1 0.70     ns       Wilco~
#>  4 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-CTR NEG-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#>  5 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-CTR NEU-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#>  6 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-NOC NEU-N~   0.7     1 0.70     ns       Wilco~
#>  7 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-CTR NEG-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#>  8 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-CTR NEU-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#>  9 L     P3(400-450).~ value NEG-NOC NEU-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#> 10 L     LPPearly(500~ value NEG-CTR NEG-N~   1       1 1.00     ns       Wilco~
#> # ... with 107 more rows
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. There is just a little adjustament I will need. If I add to your code the `%>% group_split(signals)` part, since I need to sort the data by signals it turns back small lists separated properly but in a different order then the merged outcput (as yours). If I would like to name properly each subset with the proper signals name, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: never mind. Maybe you can contribute to solve this further issue, if you would like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69905668/error-no-tidy-method-for-objects-of-class-character. Thanks