# Error: No tidy method for objects of class character

Tags: r, datatable, purrr, tidy

I'm trying to converting the following lists of elemets in a table. Here following you could find the method to create the list

```
alt_1 = data_long %>% 
  ggpubr::compare_means(value ~ COND, ., group.by = c('SES', 'signals'), method = 't.test', p.adjust.method = 'bonferroni') %>% 
  dplyr::select(., -'.y.') %>%
  group_split(signals)
```

And here as follows the one to create table

```
  alt_1 %>% 
    map(~.x %>% 
          map( ~broom::tidy(.x) %>% pull(x) %>% as_tibble() %>%               
flextable::flextable()))
```

By the way somethinf seems to go wrong since I'm keeping obtaining the following error

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class character
```

May anyone know what that error means and how to fix it?

Thanks

Here the dataset I'm working on

```
   > dput(head(data_long, 390))
structure(list(ID = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06"), GR = c("RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", "RP", 
"RP", "RP", "RP", "RP"), SES = c("L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", 
"V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R"), COND = c("NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", 
"NEG-CTR", "NEG-CTR", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", 
"NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEG-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", 
"NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC", "NEU-NOC"), signals = c("P3(400-450).FCz", 
"P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz", 
"P3(400-450).FCz", "P3(400-450).Cz", "P3(400-450).Pz", "LPPearly(500-700).FCz", 
"LPPearly(500-700).Cz", "LPPearly(500-700).Pz", "LPP1(500-1000).FCz", 
"LPP1(500-1000).Cz", "LPP1(500-1000).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).FCz", 
"LPP2(1000-1500).Cz", "LPP2(1000-1500).Pz", "LPP2(1000-1500).POz"
), value = c(-13.733750856001, -9.75024624896264, 2.65626156135631, 
-11.2145748677083, -8.14861856277773, 3.4315211013568, -7.774797181711, 
-5.0379636708446, 4.67200616533014, -0.397250087672501, 2.91913936481813, 
8.38141924882334, 9.61455213192824, -11.0706676917232, -8.42427447113084, 
3.37360619561252, -13.9481657323772, -11.7645758007163, -1.55179922542943, 
-8.40872060176111, -6.36865552801825, 1.75888442936359, 1.01519755373062, 
1.85489998202138, 4.88842858528025, 7.21299011910717, -8.4719202003519, 
-5.61886494275071, 5.4043480635031, -12.0047623683783, -9.16726244915301, 
1.13509020104859, -7.03235376576925, -4.54670193355435, 2.49276476951357, 
-1.17300033366376, 0.694393606954545, 5.0594399581601, 6.1861244061312, 
-5.04318152659785, 0.73152672768007, 19.5226358864568, -4.24372139176794, 
0.918751423320568, 16.3120391015512, -0.65010821749741, 4.05493850786385, 
13.8997702651793, 0.663115370014327, 3.95694572160701, 3.88831364571248, 
6.46723813995257, -6.25375875400145, 1.11453058993788, 18.5017390789352, 
-7.38414465678688, -0.674372568935879, 14.1694182774958, -3.24350263682843, 
2.67516303169366, 13.2135623121441, -1.72160165493474, 2.36649557381131, 
5.83201076558185, 7.25962635499353, -7.0474968134059, -2.25104720773472, 
11.7844254386573, -6.61221718491095, -2.47425935490564, 9.04781409226351, 
-2.84832379590422, 1.02479302810681, 9.51479768101391, 0.0540027107377267, 
2.71292196345657, 3.65113189260335, 7.92952342178602, -11.6312151716924, 
-5.16524399006139, 11.8802266972569, -11.7785042972793, -5.96429031525769, 
8.23981597718437, -5.67295796971287, -0.774461731301161, 9.99385579756163, 
-0.198736254963744, 2.96437294922766, 6.28027312932027, 7.91468942320841, 
-11.1438413285935, -5.53112490175437, 12.1053426662461, -9.14927207125904, 
-5.10918437158799, 9.51261484648731, -4.3918290080777, -0.650009462761383, 
11.1212652173052, -3.16101041766438, -2.12913230708907, 5.24535230966772, 
9.94838815736199, -3.99591470944713, 0.621502123415388, 12.955441582096, 
-7.58190508537766, -2.81732229625975, 9.42367409925817, -2.96652960658775, 
1.14010250644923, 10.6989716871958, 0.895992279831378, 2.94619035115619, 
7.68162285335806, 10.2186482048953, 8.71618523084192, 10.0972150696175, 
13.9718285231429, 14.2438131545118, 18.1277616996079, 20.6284861844249, 
12.5228696634748, 15.0856583318757, 15.4011622649207, 9.21248347391488, 
10.0673617448764, 8.55827491190151, 5.76901446016799, 3.1567164130045, 
3.29671672118792, 6.37710361710325, 10.3728637305957, 14.0324104861749, 
17.1194345279475, 10.1688421767607, 12.7218688256241, 13.5845965959489, 
4.2029104966206, 5.28032844958354, 4.37390045274906, 1.63411653734436, 
0.11779005903818, 0.527314779744752, 3.52040283490143, 4.71555467505934, 
7.88901307601169, 9.74981375898379, 4.94891653050796, 7.04929483656524, 
7.62145250862908, 5.29260474692784, 5.76317883868431, 4.27567967018154, 
2.14044069620066, 6.2230923800622, 7.48013969467974, 13.9681839573434, 
8.16263381384371, 10.9263261999576, 15.5578942384162, 8.29234474523583, 
9.71944484568732, 12.4214977980377, 4.43538787409554, 4.54790063971537, 
6.04702803069286, 4.09091078261671, 0.545039723311392, 2.24297008138028, 
8.64955428897889, 2.54754270788021, 5.40070389371842, 10.3425870381822, 
2.89989209310052, 5.19815917760722, 8.94731174966949, 1.28346027317076, 
2.16569592764593, 5.29458007289059, 5.32593378182311, -0.383605036065646, 
-0.0523505792147314, 2.80847380898547, -1.01463338713448, 0.139150314055044, 
3.41932708826405, 1.69916872833203, 2.20513206952329, 4.10953557761617, 
1.17003451023205, 1.33824716938448, 1.21234812875355, -0.0587064331536407, 
-2.10936383457265, 0.0473343786951428, 10.1644392609445, -6.4216236476269, 
-4.61042211238648, 4.05274207265641, -1.13332962482291, -0.20305866581144, 
5.80373742668179, 3.21881665778703, 2.58426832963409, 6.30887598671621, 
6.86490468078958, 1.81064934015995, 2.78240093455642, 13.2788201390174, 
-4.08374576377548, -3.5562551128714, 3.767844291789, 0.649857280429136, 
1.01053594416015, 5.74639215930458, 5.92604591551597, 5.077230852852, 
5.9614279900414, 5.26280996552585, 0.754416368133019, 2.60057993978525, 
10.5077997492971, -8.46742290376216, -6.85651693740331, 0.326110657534835, 
-4.43684347222634, -2.96241685765962, 1.48762660613099, -2.75555354427229, 
-1.59699177169018, -0.609381826740468, 0.981300734684586, -1.2371236814317, 
1.4302038359579, 13.4030666728381, -6.30908300837476, -2.17237957159954, 
6.65839865279684, -2.31574543509226, 1.26480036715092, 6.04018553841336, 
2.18006640865321, 6.61872855398538, 3.66646157996528, 5.0384350436334, 
-2.76852389876276, -0.650797837853182, 4.74014346829081, -6.72661142802369, 
-6.18867237684241, 1.17003883692158, -2.73359549382074, -2.00512841997728, 
1.9050381096835, -0.225533814334514, -1.21696526578647, 0.240956222277802, 
0.361670119961531, 5.54144355778122, 7.81248993867768, 11.9003140352528, 
-3.32736490042247, -1.77938930999718, 5.40630013085777, -0.38736451456005, 
-0.423105565152366, 6.37211228749408, 0.986467266459687, -0.507207892673482, 
1.15053325116554, 0.393791410918138, -0.314155675382471, 2.23100741241039, 
15.0981004360619, -4.01515836011381, -1.43557366487622, 5.06332653216481, 
0.159183652691071, 1.51403741206392, 3.7899021820967, 3.11042068112836, 
3.44844607014521, 1.08242973465635, 1.07455889922813, 0.238885648959708, 
3.96990710862955, 15.4046229884164, -6.60165385653499, -3.14872157912645, 
5.02619159395405, -1.78361184935376, 0.25571835554024, 4.59413830322224, 
2.27800090558473, 3.02403433835637, 2.99896314000211, 1.65917850515029, 
5.03749946898385, 7.75899775608441, 16.671036999147, -2.02861964460179, 
0.160393685024631, 9.07903916629231, 1.97377908783621, 3.76051565494304, 
8.52123662617732, 3.83846437952292, 4.7045767546583, 5.36085942954182, 
3.22422743232682, 0.515492206557273, 0.204266730001714, 6.24616732032065, 
5.8666814083179, 6.04784652351361, 11.3067210486656, 6.83112977894818, 
6.84424120299137, 11.0326576935158, 2.11741401205978, 1.31359485387859, 
2.79229514887897, 4.15964501337974, -3.44241289723487, -3.87922889171612, 
4.78883251402879, 2.33082585113171, 3.3201189812225, 9.74936883279237, 
1.66856860799729, 3.42983447849866, 8.53328996612415, 2.41324857857743, 
3.04464581710327, 5.44503756798021, 5.35297505953096, -3.60371878191807, 
-4.52390680893631, 3.10163832479954, 2.40451234371064, 2.77790257477581, 
9.14893956441953, 1.50685192543202, 1.92879865454881, 7.97978028439358, 
2.60828710695631, 2.0247782323911, 5.10559083807721, 7.08169531735032, 
2.15744073519755, -0.555866517774192, 7.19701911286765, 1.05508424329473, 
-0.0321863430056016, 7.00923591763326, 2.41771490245341, 1.33136574265339, 
8.06029747262827, 1.84146702695206, -1.66589658134171, 4.18316343024083, 
4.11643541344308, 2.97044048166016, 4.83800866902117, 11.7708849923357, 
5.3097315293492, 8.03888173016662, 15.2010764804929, 4.37926203865435, 
7.29405407117465, 13.6951238953551, 2.1796529384155, 2.27922842547595, 
7.57635217480856, 6.89982254066399, 0.826471695322022, 0.386260399882896, 
4.76130184268843, 1.70929976001852, 2.16769713008185, 8.29325466843138, 
0.172003204109993, 0.983842959739636, 5.8513720384409, 0.357695315581409, 
2.2302354828667, 4.02825376191901, 5.50985275336188)), row.names = c(NA, 
-390L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: Maybe it is the version.  Can you show the versions of package used i..e `ggpubr`

Comment: It's the 0.4.0, I've checked right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do the `tidy` because the output is already a `tibble` - check the `str` of the first element

```
> str(alt_1[[1]])
tibble [9 × 9] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ SES     : chr [1:9] "L" "L" "L" "R" ...
 $ signals : chr [1:9] "LPP1(500-1000).Cz" "LPP1(500-1000).Cz" "LPP1(500-1000).Cz" "LPP1(500-1000).Cz" ...
 $ group1  : chr [1:9] "NEG-CTR" "NEG-CTR" "NEG-NOC" "NEG-CTR" ...
 $ group2  : chr [1:9] "NEG-NOC" "NEU-NOC" "NEU-NOC" "NEG-NOC" ...
 $ p       : num [1:9] 0.811 0.49 0.642 0.786 0.212 ...
 $ p.adj   : num [1:9] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ p.format: chr [1:9] "0.811" "0.490" "0.642" "0.786" ...
 $ p.signif: chr [1:9] "ns" "ns" "ns" "ns" ...
 $ method  : chr [1:9] "T-test" "T-test" "T-test" "T-test" ...
```

It implies that we can directly apply the `flextable` on the `tibble` and store it in a `list`

```
library(purrr)
library(flextable)
alt_2 <- map(alt_1, ~ flextable(.x) %>%
     colformat_double(digits = 2) %>% 
     theme_box() %>% 
     valign(valign = "center") %>% autofit() %>% 
     set_caption(caption = sprintf('Statistics of %s', first(.x$signals))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You always save me. Can you remember the issue I had to assign table? There will be the same. Just I need to assign to each table an heading like 'Statistics of (name of signals)? What I should modify in your code?

Comment: I mean this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843422/tables-assignation-for-reiterated-flextable

Comment: @mały_statystyczny  Please check if the update helps

Comment: Really man, thank you very much. I wouldn't like to take advantage from you, but you're such a genius. This is the very final round for my analysis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899642/how-to-create-by-an-iterative-method-a-series-of-boxplots-with-statistics-annota. I should report this pairwise comparisons into some boxplots iteratively. If you could guide me, I'll be very glad.

Comment: @mały_statystyczny thanks, will look into it.  If I come across anything, will post. thanks

Comment: really, You seems to manage quite easily these iterative method. I do not know I either I could ask here or privately, but I was wondering wether I can ask you to give me some lessons. Seriously

Comment: @mały_statystyczny i haven't used the compare_means before.  So, I am not sure if I can come up with a solution

Comment: Can you provide any further ways, possibly?

Comment: @mały_statystyczny i have to leave now.  Will check later. thanks